# zrssfeed JQUery crash on IE 9, force to close

Tags: jquery, iframe, tabs, rss, internet-explorer-9

The ZRSSFeed JQuery working fine if standalone  but it will crash with IE 9 once I put it in the iFrame with the JQuery tabs. (I thought iFrame should not have JQuery conflict?)

You can have a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/VMfXr/

Simply copy and paste the URL to the IE and it force my IE 9 to close. Appreciate if there is any help.

or the following codes:

```
<div class="widget_container"> <div class="widget_container_inner">
            <ul class='tabs'>
                <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3">JQuery Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id='tab1'>
            <Script>window.console && console.log('tab1');</script></div>
            <div id='tab2'>
            <Script>window.console && console.log('tab2');</script>
            </div>
            <div id='tab3'> <Script>window.console && console.log('tab3');</script>
                <iFrame src="http://www.iframeURL.com" style="width:320px; height:330px; overflow:hidden" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iFrame>
            </div>
        </div> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
        jQuery.noConflict();
        (function($) {                                           
           jQuery(document).ready(function($) {         
               jQuery('ul.tabs').each(function(){           
                   var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
                   $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);            
                   $active.addClass('active');          
                   $content = $($active.attr('href'));

               $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $($(this).attr('href')).hide();             });

            jQuery(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $content.hide();
                $active = $(this);
                $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.show();
                e.preventDefault();             
                     });        
                 });    
            }); 
       })(jQuery); </script>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of your jquery.vticker.js file running in the iframe while it is hidden.  This seems to be a bug in IE9 with a recent update.  What's happening is IE is getting an access violation, this can be a result of the garbage collector not working properly on hidden i-frames.  Regardless, To fix the bug you can comment out the following lines of code from your jquery.vticker.js that is referenced by http://www.sp.edu.sg/schools/dmit/widgets/ticker/blog/blog_widget_dbit.html

```
obj.children('ul').children('li').each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxHeight);
});

obj.height(maxHeight * options.showItems);
```

This seems to be related to Microsoft KB2761451, which was a security update that came out on November 13th, 2012.

Comment: This is definitely related to KB2761451. You can verify by uninstall that KB and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

My company had this issue in our product, opened a support ticket with Microsoft and they fixed the issue. The last patch should stop IE9 from crashing.