# Internet Explorer crashing when iframe containing javascript is hidden

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

Yesterday we identified a problem with one of our sites crashing whenever the iframe on the homepage was hidden, and it was only happening on IE9. The iFrame contained some simple html and a slideshow, which was being run with jquery. Why would this cause a crash in IE but not the other browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On nov 13 microsoft released a security update for IE (KB2761451) that is responsible for this issue. Internet explorer will throw an access violation if javascript is run inside a hidden iframe. I suspect this was done to close some cross site scripting vulnerability but I don't think this is the intended behavior.

[Similar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450190/zrssfeed-jquery-crash-on-ie-9-force-to-close)

[Microsoft's update page for KB2761451](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-071)

Comment: This was fixed in IE9 in a later update (see the last comment on the similar answer), and is confirmed to still be an issue on IE8, but not IE9 running in IE8 compatibility mode. Without preventing the iframe from being hidden, the only solutions are to roll back this update, or upgrade to IE9+.